# Node-sass auto generates CSS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

I've recently started a new react project using CRA with typescript and as usual added node-sass to support sass and for the first I am seeing that when I save the sass file a CSS file is created in the directory.

How do I stop the package from auto generating css?

Comment: Why would you like to stop the css generation? .scss needs to be compiled to css for the browser.

Comment: well, in the previous project it was compiled into a single file. In the current project is being compile one per file.

Comment: Then you need to update your question with relevant info.